# How can I better read my socket?

Tags: c, sockets

This just gets stuck every time I loop it. It sits waiting to read but never reads anything, because, well.. there's nothing left to read.

Here's the read function:

```
int  readSocket(int sockfd, char* buffer) {

    FILE* file;
    file = fopen("logfile.txt","a+");

    char code[5];

    while(1) {

        int nBytes = read(sockfd, buffer, MY_BUFFER_SIZE);
        fprintf(file,"S->C: %s",buffer);

        strncpy(code, buffer,4); 
        code[4]='\0';



            if (nBytes == 0) break;

        memset(buffer, 0, MY_BUFFER_SIZE);

    }
    fclose(file);
    return codeParser(atoi(code));
}
```

Here's what's calling it:

```
while (1) {
    serverCode = readSocket(sockfd, mybuffer);
    if (serverCode == 221) break;

    fflush (stdout);
    buffer = fgets (mybuffer, 1024, stdin); 

    writeSocket(sockfd, mybuffer);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TCP socket is a bi-directional stream. It does not know about your message boundaries. You need your own *protocol* on top of TCP to figure out separate messages. <del>Two</del> Three common approaches are:

- fixed-length messages,
- length of the message embedded into fixed-length message header,
- explicit message delimiter, say a new-line, or `\0x1`, etc. (thanks, @caf).

#### Edit 0:

Some notes about your code:

1. Always check return values of system calls like `read(2)`. First, it might be `-1`, i.e. an error, so you have to examine [`errno(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html); second, you might read less then 4 bytes you are expecting.
2. `nBytes == 0` is the `EOF` case, meaning other side closed the connection.
3. You don't need the `memset()` there.

Comment: A short answer to a long question. And true. :-)

Comment: I don't have server side access, so I suppose one way to do this would be to define a smaller buffer length and then keep reading until the buffer is less than full?

Comment: No, it will never work reliably. If you didn't write the server, someone did and defined some protocol.

Comment: Yeah -- I just have to figure out the maximum number of characters on each line returned by FTP. You may know this already, but just for others, the server returns lines like so: `[code][space][message]` -- if the `[space]` is actually a dash (`230-Welcome!`), then there is more to come. Right now, with a 1024 byte buffer, my socket reads the entire message and dumps it out as one long message. If I just knew how many bytes to read on each line, I'd be ok.

Comment: Yes, that'd be sensible thing to do :) I'll update the answer with some nitpicks about the code.

Comment: Haha, great. Straight from the RFC: A reply is defined to contain the 3-digit code, followed by Space<SP>, followed by one line of text (where some maximum line length
      has been specified)

Comment: Oh by the way, the reason I added memset is because my buffer was holding the old chars, so when it printed out it would keep the extra junk from the previous read. I guess at \0 would prevent that, though..

Comment: @Brian D: FTP uses a third method for delimiting messages - a fixed delimiter character (in the case of FTP, that character is the newline).

Comment: @caf, thanks, I was just thinking about adding that third option :)

Comment: There you have it. Thanks Nikolai and caf -- I implemented some checks to run through the buffer stream, and if I run into a newline, parse the code and subsequent delimiter and deal with the buffer-reading loop accordingly. Seems to work!

Comment: @Brian, one more thing - if you are serious about network programming, get yourself a copy of this book - http://www.unpbook.com